# Silverlight Textbox_LostFocus event not firing on Button_Click

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have one textbox and a Save Button in my silverlight. The validations for the textbox are in its lostFocus event. But if I enter something in the textbox and directly press the save button, the validation is not working. In other words, the lostfocus event is not raising in the button_click event. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Call `Focus()` on the button. For instance, if your button's name is "MyButton", you may use `MyButton.Focus()` inside of it's click event. 
I would also suggest that you simply call your textbox validation method inside of your button press event, then proceed only if all validations are successful.